# Kable produces HTML not markdown

Tags: r-markdown, kable

When I use `kable` in an R console and use the 'pipe' format, I get Markdown.

```
> knitr::kable(head(mtcars), format="pipe", padding = 1)


|                  |  mpg| cyl| disp|  hp| drat|    wt|  qsec| vs| am| gear| carb|
|:-----------------|----:|---:|----:|---:|----:|-----:|-----:|--:|--:|----:|----:|
|Mazda RX4         | 21.0|   6|  160| 110| 3.90| 2.620| 16.46|  0|  1|    4|    4|
|Mazda RX4 Wag     | 21.0|   6|  160| 110| 3.90| 2.875| 17.02|  0|  1|    4|    4|
```

However, if I put the same line of code into an R Markdown file...

```
---
title: I Want Markdown!
author: Me!
output: md_document
---

The block below uses three backticks but I only use two here because I didn't know how to nest a code block within another code block in Stack.

``{r}
knitr::kable(head(mtcars), format="pipe", padding = 1)
``
```

And then run that from a command line with:

```bash
Rscript -e "rmarkdown::render('md.rmd')"
```

The resulting Markdown file has an HTML table.  Is there something I can do to have a table in the requested pipe/Markdown format inside my rendered Markdown file?

I'm using R v.4.0.4 on Linux in case that matters.

Answer (score 0):

You can write an own function such that kable results are printed as text not as HTML tables, see [here](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown-cookbook/blob/master/10-tables.Rmd):

````
---
title: I Want Markdown!
author: Me!
output: md_document
---

```{r, echo=FALSE}
# print kable() results as text instead of real tables
kat = function(x, ...) {
  if (length(x) > 0) x[1] = gsub('^\n+', '', x[1])
  x = gsub('\n\n+', '\n', x)
  cat(x, sep = '\n')
}
```


```{r, render=kat}
knitr::kable(head(mtcars), format="pipe", padding = 1)
```
````

[image]